# Fill in the Dashes : Part 3 of 10 - Comic Superheroes Alter-egos

Tags: knowledge

This is part of the [Fill in the Dashes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22Fill%20in%20the%20Dashes%22) series of puzzles.

**Example:**
F_ in the B_   ⇒  Fill in the Blanks

**Some of the words will be Juxtaposed as in:**
B_ F_ in the   ⇒  Fill in the Blanks

**e.g.:** C_ K_ S_    ⇒  Clark Kent Superman or Superman Clark Kent

**Can you identify these?**

1) B_ B_ W_

2) E_ K_ S_

3) I_ S_ T_

4) P_ P_ S_

5) A_ A_ J_ C_

6) D_ P_ W_ W_

7) A_ C_ R_ S_

8) D_ G_ R_

9) B_ B_ H_

10) I_ S_ S_ W_

11) N_ R_ S_ S_

12) A_ G_ O_ Q_

13) C_ B_ H_

14) S_ W_ W_

15) D_ M_ M_

16) K_ P_ W_

17) B_ I_ M_ P_

Comment: A clue for #5??

Comment: @CodeNewbie AJC A :-)

Comment: Got it! Answer edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2

> Kal-El, Superman

3

> Tony Stark, IronMan

8

> Dick Grayson, Robin

10

> Susan Storm, Invisible Woman

13

> Clint Barton, Hawkeye

14

> Simon Williams, Wonderman

15

> Matt Murdock, Daredevil

Comment: A A J C is the only one left

Answer (score 5):

1.

> Batman, Bruce Wayne

4.

> Peter Parker, Spiderman

5.

> Aquaman, Arthur Joseph Curry

9.

> Bruce Banner, Hulk

11.

> Norin Radd, Silver Surfer

13.

> Clint Barton, Hawkeye

16.

> Kit Walker, Phantom

17.

> Bob Parr, Mr Incredible

Comment: Well Done !!! #5 is right.

Comment: @kanchirk: Superb puzzle!

Comment: @CodeNewbie Thank you. Appreciate it. I am puzzled about whose answer should I accept. I have upvoted all the answers.

Comment: @pacoverflow Actually I am most likely not correct... I got the Arthur Curry/Aquaman connection, but I wasn't aware of a middle name, so I googled Arthur Curry Jr and got a few hits so I assumed it was referring to Arthur Curry/Aquaman.... However, Arthur Curry Jr apparently refers to the son of Arthur Curry/Aquaman (imagine that...) aka "Aquababy" whom isn't really a Superhero (I don't think)... On the other hand I'm not sure why Aquaman deserves a middle name when all of the others do not....

Comment: @kanchirk That is the main reason I don't like the question (I like the idea/puzzle itself. I don't like that the question has 17 sub-answers)... the 17 sub-answers isn't really ideal for the site format, but on the other hand you can't really split them up into 17 separate questions.

Comment: @Warlord099 I agree.. The next puzzle in the series has a clue in each of the answer which adds up to a final answer. Anyone who gets it right first with reasoning will be awarded. I started the series small to see the interest and I aim to appeal to the general puzzlers from wide area of interests.

Answer (score 4):

6) D_ P_ W_ W_

> Diana Prince, Wonder Woman

7) A_ C_ R_ S_

> Captain America, Steve Rogers

12) A_ G_ O_ Q_

> Green Arrow, Oliver Queen